# Как запустить заданное количество вложенных циклов без рекурсии

Tags: циклы, c++

допустим есть функция

```
    void cicl(){
       for(...){
         for(...){
`          for(...){
             cout << "работает вложенных три цикла" << endl;
           }
        `}
       }
    }
```

а если надо такую функцию которая создает 10000 вложенных циклов.

```
void cicl(unsigned int num_cicle=10000){
  // не будем же мы здесь писать 10000 вложенных циклов
}
```

как осуществить такое **не прибегая к рекурсии**?

Comment: хоть намёк на пример использования? зачем?

Comment: Какое-то жутко бредовое задание. Учитывая, что крутится только внутренний цикл.

Comment: 10000 вложенных циклов с n итерациями - это один цикл с 10000^n итерациями. а в вопросе и правда цикл один - внутренний.

Comment: я while для примера привел а так для всех циклов подразаумевал

Comment: поправлю чтоб понятно было

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно организовать вложеные циклы, то нужен только массив для хранения индексов.

Пусть нужно n вложенных циклов, но максимальное значение - m.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int n = 3;
    const int m = 4;
    int ind[n] = {0};
    int c = pow(m,n); // степень, может быть вычислена сразу.
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      // это такое тело цикла - вывод индеков
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          std::cout << ind[j] << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;

      // ключевая часть - обновим индексы
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          ind[j]++;
          if (ind[j] < m)
            break;
          ind[j] = 0;
      }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если индексы должны быть разные, то нужен ещё один массив индексов и проверки должны быть не с m, а с элементами этого массива.

У этого кода есть много недостатков, к примеру, можно от параметра цикла i избавиться (при больших вложенности может быть переполнение). Но это легко при желании доработать. Также, возможно, нужно будет использовать вектор. Но не буду же я весь код за Вас делать:)

По факту - это идентично обычной позиционной системе счисления.

Comment: идея понятна, мне подходит

Comment: @perfect вот пример ухода от кучи вложенных циклов и рекурсии [ХК#107519](http://hashcode.ru/questions/107519/javascript-как-сделать-такой-же-код-без-eval-a). То, как раз о чем в ответе @KoVadim.

Answer (score 3):

Любую рекурсию можно организовать через цикл `while` с использованием стека.

не на С++, но [Явное использование стека](http://www.tvd-home.ru/recursion#p7)

Comment: надо без рекурсии, стек очень ограничен

Comment: используя стек можно обойтись без рекурсии. Чем именно он ограничен? для полного понимания хорошо было бы пример или описание.